# Ubuntu 20.04 brightness

Tags: 20.04, brightness

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my AMD ryzen 7 computer and i have noticed that the brightness controller is not working. I have tried installing some apps, changing /etc/default/grub and I don't have the X11/xorg_config...
i followed the steps in the website
(https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/10/2-ways-fix-laptop-brightness-problem-ubuntu-linux/)

any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

Then, you need to edit the value of some of this. REMEMBER that 0 is for no brigthness, so the range could be 50 to 100.

```
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: I tried to, but it doesn't accept it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue with ryzen 4000 series which is not supported by the kernel 5.4.
Ubuntu 20.04 is using kernel 5.4 as default kernel.
You can install ubuntu 20.10 with kernel 5.8 or upgrade ubuntu 20.04 to kernel 5.8.

Comment: Can you provide some reference that kernel 5.8 would support it?

Comment: this is link for the reference https://www.fosslinux.com/42624/top-10-new-features-in-linux-kernel-5-8.htm